# Debugging QuickLook plug-in with 'bundle is damaged' error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bundle, appkit, quicklook

We're adding a QuickLook plug-in to our project.

Everything is fine until macOS trying to invoke our plug-in, at which point we're getting the beloved **The bundle couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources** error.

We've checked with `otool -L` on the plug-in's binary that all dependencies are in place, however as soon as the OS is asking our plug-in for a preview for the file type supported by us we get:

```
22/04/17 12:03:05,716 quicklookd[55323]: 
[QL] Can't load plug-in at file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Project-gpihzjouhxvifqcslmywktktizer/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/SomeQuickLookPlugIn.qlgenerator/: 
The bundle “SomeQuickLookPlugIn” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.
```

The one thing we're not quite sure about is the dependency to our internal frameworks.

We've set up the plug-in similar to our main app, i.e. the private framework dependency resolves to:

`@executable_path/../Frameworks/MyFW.framework/Versions/A/MyFW (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`

..which would work OK if `@executable_path` were either the main app's binary or the plug-in's main binary as we copied the frameworks in both places in the bundle.

Any thoughts?

Ideally we would like the OS to tell us *which* dependency it failed to resolve -
is there any debug flag that can be set..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html and http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/ you should

- set the **Installation Directory** for your referenced framework(s) to `@rpath`
- in the app set **Runtime Search Paths** to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`
- and in the QuickLook plug-in set **Runtime Search Paths** to `@loader_path/../../../../../Frameworks` as suggested by ***catlan***  -
  that way you don't need to duplicate referenced frameworks inside the QuickLook plug-in

Compile, run, and everything should just work if everything else is set up correctly.

In addition you might want to check the code-signing settings in your plug-in to make sure there's no problems there.

One thing you can do is remove (or turn-off) code signing from your app and then see if it will load the plug-in…

To check if code-signing is the problem you can turn it off temporarily for your app using the Terminal to `codesign --remove-signature YourApp.app` and see if it works..

Answer (score 0):

Run Search Paths should be `@loader_path/../../../../../Frameworks` because it is installed into `Main.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/QuickLookPlugin.qlgenerator/Contents/Mac/QuickLookPlugin`, so we need to go five folders down from the @loader_path to find the frameworks folder.

Comment: Cheers - I'm copying the frameworks to the plug-in's frameworks folder as well, though.
Any idea how to figure out *what* the OS cannot resolve?

Comment: 1) I don't see a reason to copy the frameworks into the plug-ins frameworks folder, it just increases the memory footprint. 2) Maybe you get a better error message when you try to load the plug-in yourself in the app `[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/Library/QuickLook/SomeQuickLookPlugIn.qlgenerator"]] load]`

Comment: good point - changed that to just reference the parent bundle's resources